# Combined queries from one collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with following structure.

```
{
     sourceName: ’mySourceName1’,
     date: ‘October’,
     metadata:[
     {‘key’: ‘userName’, ‘value’ : ‘user1’},
     {‘key’: ‘instrumentName’, ‘value’ : ‘instrument1’}
     ]}
     {
     sourceName: ’mySourceName2’,
     date: ‘November’,
     metadata:[
     {‘key’: ‘userName’, ‘value’ : ‘user2’},
     {‘key’: ‘instrumentName’, ‘value’ : ‘instrument2’}
     ]}
```

**How I can make a query like:**

```
Select * from Data where sourceName in (‘mySourceName1’, ’mySourceName2’) and   (key=’userName’ and value=’user1’) and (key=’..’ and value = ‘..’) ….
```

I managed to make the query except the ‘in’ part by :

```
$all:[{$elemMatch:{‘key’:’userName’, ‘value’: ‘user1’}},{$elemMatch:{‘key’:  ‘instrumentName’, ‘value’: ‘instrument2’}]
```

How can I add ‘in’ part? Do I need to make two queries? I tried to combine $all and $in but it failed.
I am interested to get the solution with the best performance.

Thanks,

Comment: just a comment but why do you form your metadata like this and not like  `metadata: [ { userName: 'user1'}, { instrumentName: 'instrument1'}]` ?

Comment: because I have very different metadata and I want to define index on them using this generic format.In this example both documents have the same metadata, however, it is not the real case.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for MongoDB, however given your specific use case for a query what you need is the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator. What this does is wraps the logical statements to match, which is what [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) does in a simplified way:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
         {
             "sourceName": "mySourceName1",
             "metadata": { 
                 "$all": [
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "userName", "value": "user1"
                     }},
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "instrumentName", "value": "instrument1"
                     }}
                 ]
             }
         },
         {
             "sourceName": "mySourceName2",
             "metadata": { 
                 "$all": [
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "userName", "value": "user2"
                     }},
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "instrumentName", "value": "instrument2"
                     }}
                 ]
             }
         }
     ]
})
```

Effectively that is one big "in" statement where you are supplying the sets of criteria to match.

If you actually intend not to "tie" those "sourceName" values to the other matching criteria, then you can actually write this using the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator as well:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "sourceName": { "$in": [ "mySourceName1", "mySourceName2" ] },
    "$or": [
         {
             "metadata": { 
                 "$all": [
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "userName", "value": "user1"
                     }},
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "instrumentName", "value": "instrument1"
                     }}
                 ]
             }
         },
         {
             "metadata": { 
                 "$all": [
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "userName", "value": "user2"
                     }},
                     { "$elemMatch": {
                         "key": "instrumentName", "value": "instrument2"
                     }}
                 ]
             }
         }
     ]
})
```

As all MongoDB queries are implicitly "and" conditions, this says that the "sourceName" can be either "mySourceName1" or "mySourceName2" and that the other criteria can be either of those other conditions that match.

So it depends on your intent as to how "tied" you intend the logic to be, but those are the essential approaches.